# Unix serial port programming: How to get number of bytes in output buffer?

Tags: c, unix, serial-port

I know it is possible to get the number of bytes in the serial port input buffer using ioctl with FIONREAD as an example shows in "Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems" (link: http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1_3). Is there a way to do the same for the output buffer?

I ask because I want to know when all bytes have been transmitted.

On Windows, this can be done by looking at cbOutQue in the COMSTAT structure but I still have not found a way to do that in Unix based systems.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS supports it you could consider the ioctl TIOCOUTQ.

Like TIOCINQ/FIONREAD it's not POSIX though.

Comment: Thanks. Reading TIOCOUTQ with ioctl returns 0 at all times. Is this because Mac OS X does not support it? I can't find much information about TIOCOUTQ on the Internet...

Comment: Based on this [man-page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/tty.4.html) it looks like Mac OS X at least supported TIOCOUTQ at v10.9.

To ensure you get a non-zero output buffer queue size, you may want to enable hardware flow control (RTS/CTS) and disconnect the physical serial cable, then I think you should see the queue size growing when you write to the serial port.

Comment: Thank you :-) Good idea to test with RTS/CTS flow control. I will be back after some testing.